# working with update on sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

M database structure look like this
my table is named `others` while the column is `sleep,water and smoke`

by the way, this is my add sleep function in mainactivity

```
final Integer newSleep = sleep; // this is the number picker
repo repo = new repo(MainActivity.this);
others sleep = new others();

sleep.sleep = others_id;
sleep.sleep=newSleep;

repo.updateSleep(sleep);
```

this is my repo

```
public int updateSleep(others sleep) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_sleep, sleep.sleep);
    values.put(KEY_water, sleep.water);
    values.put(KEY_smoke, sleep.smoke);

    return db.update(others.TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(sleep.others_id)});
}
```

PS: I only included the add sleep function so that i will be able to easily understand it.

Comment: So is not a code writing service. And a Q&A site is not appropriate for learning the basics of Java and Android.

Comment: Yes I know sir, but the thing is, I have codes that can insert a data but just like what ive said, it is so messed up, so now, im trying to reformat my codes. you can refer my problem here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053563/sqlite-data-put-only-in-one-row-and-how-to-sum-data